# GCP - Unable to access saved model file on GCP bucket in main.py

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded a PyTorch checkpoint file 'checkpoint_ic_d161.pth' to a GCP bucket.

I am trying to upload a PyTorch Flask model to GCP App Engine in order to make a simple web app.

But I'm not able to access the model file from the GCP bucket into my main.py in the App Engine.

```
MODEL_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/end_to_end_challenge_bucket/checkpoint_ic_d161.pth'

def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = checkpoint['model']
    model.classifier = checkpoint['classifier']
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    model.class_to_idx = checkpoint['class_to_idx']
    optimizer = checkpoint['optimizer']
    epochs = checkpoint['epochs']
    
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
        
    return model, checkpoint['class_to_idx']


def get_model():
    model, class_to_idx = load_checkpoint(MODEL_URL)
    model.eval()
    return model
```

I get a FileNotFound error for https://storage.googleapis.com/end_to_end_challenge_bucket/checkpoint_ic_d161.pth although this is the public access to the file in the bucket.

Why is this so, how can I access the model /checkpoint file stored in my GCP bucket, within my main.py for the GCP App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

In order to download and upload to Cloud Storage files you **need to use the Cloud Storage libraries**. As it is [not supported by PyTorch.](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/will-pytorch-support-cloud-storage/24869/10)

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

[Upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#code-samples)

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

[Download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#python)

```
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```